# Does ICanvas.DrawString work on Net Maui for MacCataylst?

Tags: maui, maui.mac

ICanvas.DrawString only tosses exceptions on NetMaui when trying to develop code for the Mac platform.

Has this ever been fixed? This is an essential part of functionality.

Where can you report bugs to the Net Maui team?

Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: Is this about the errors you see (but didn't share) or is it about where to report bugs?

Comment: This is about both. As mentioned the DrawString method does not work at all on the Mac Platform. I saw a post about this from 2022 where the dev team was calling it a low priority issue, when it is a complete lack of functionality. Does anyone write code in NetMaui for the mac?

Answer (score 0):

Net Maui has two DrawString methods on ICanvas. The one that takes a bounding box works. The one that takes only the starting X and Y location of the string does not work and tosses an exception every time when run on MacCatalyst.

Tim reached out to me from the GitHub link and I am now able to workaround the problem.

Thanks,
Gerry